# How to run adb push as root?

Tags: android, adb, root, pull

I want to use `adb pull` to pull a db file from Nexus 7 to PC.

My nexus 7 has been rooted.

If a use "`adb pull /data/data/com.xx.xx/databases/xx.db` .",
 it failed because of permission problem. But if I use `">adb shell; >su"`, but then I can't use `"adb pull"` command.

Comment: I don't own a rooted device to check, but my guess is that the ADB Daemon `adbd` process (on the device) has to be running as `root` in order to perform this action. Kill it and start it up with `root` privileges.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it probably belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/. Generally, `adb` needs to run with root privileges (insecure mode) for this to work.

Comment: @soulseekah It is not as simple as that, because adbd drops root privileges automatically. This can be controlled by system properties if you are using a custom ROM. Otherwise there is this: http://www.xda-developers.com/android/run-adbd-in-root-mode-with-adbd-insecure/

Comment: did you try adb root command before doing adb pull?

Comment: Of course what you run on the host doesn't matter. `adbd` on *the device* needs to run as root. And it will only run as root on an engineering/debug build. On a user build, it will refuse to start as root. If it works, you are probably using a custom ROM, but still starting `adb start-server` as root has nothing to do with that (that only makes it easier to access the USB device your device is connected to).

Comment: Thanks everybody. Nikolay Elenkov is right, I tried "adb root" but if failed as I the ROM is production building. "adbd on the device needs to run as root".

Comment: you could copy the file to your SD card and then adb pull

Comment: This is a relevant software development question.